# Custom Post type: Labels are not showing

Tags: custom-post-types

I created custom-post-type.php file in folder of mu-plugins:

```
    <?php 

function custom_post_types(){
    register_post_type('event', array(
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Events',
            'edit_item'=>'Edit Event',
            'edit_posts' => 'Add New Event',
            'all_items' => 'All Events'
        ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar'
    ));
  }
  
  add_action('init', 'custom_post_types');
```

These two labels name of `'edit_item'=> 'Edit Event', & 'edit_posts' => 'Add New Event'` not working. I wanted to know where i am mistaken. Can somebody help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have put these labels inside the `capabilities` argument, which is incorrect. They should be in `labels` argument.
2. There is not `edit_posts` label, and you're missing most labels. There's many more labels you need to provide. They are listed here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_labels/

Comment: wait i corrected my code because my files has different one. because i am trying continously. Still trying. after labels not working still.

Comment: You still have not addressed #2. There are many labels, so you’re probably not looking in the right place for the ones you have provided.

Comment: not working after adding label `add_new`